# Getting "Application failed codesign verification. ... " warning after adding Distribution configuration to xcode - how to solve this?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I went step-by-step for about 5 hours through the process of adding an Distribution configuration to xcode.

After that, I keep getting this error even when I build with my Debug Configuration:

```
 Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
```

The only weird thing I had to do was this:
I've added an strange "Entitlement" file the way Apple said in the Provisioning Portal. Did exactly what they said.

I can build my app and it runs on the device, but I get that warning. Now what? Any way to solve this, or must I start from scratch for another 3 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on your Target, choose Get Info and click on the Build tab. Change the Configuration menu to match the correct distribution method (i.e. Ad Hoc Distribution or App Store Distribution). Then go to the "Code Signing" section, Code Signing Identity. Is your distribution certificate specified here?

I'm assuming you're doing an Ad Hoc build, since that's the only build type that uses the Entitlements.plist file.

Comment: I've set it correctly to the Distribution profile for App Store (no Ad Hoc), and the Code Sign Identity is set to the distribution cert. ...the build works and runs on the device, but still getting this odd warning. I had tried an Ad Hoc build before that, though...